# How to view workspace in R

Tags: r, windows

I'm trying to learn R (via [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U4-RnTW5dfw)) and immediately ran into problems.  As directed, I created a dataset in Excel with column A being numbers 1 through 10 and column B being random integers. Saved as .xlsx and .csv.

Next I tried to read the data in R with

```
> data1 <- read.table(file.choose(), header=TRUE, sep="\t")
```

and that's as far as I got.  There's no **Workspace** like in the video, or an option anywhere to view it.  There are many windows in the video, but I only have "R Console".

So, how do I get the workspace?

Comment: You might look at other resources too. [A (very) short introduction to R](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Torfs+Brauer-Short-R-Intro.pdf) walks through a lot of these set-up and installation basics.

Answer (score 3):

You may be looking for "R Studio." It's a user-friendly shell that sits on top of R... It shows you your current work space, etc.

http://www.rstudio.com/

Also, you want to use `sep=","` not `sep="\t"` if you have a CSV. `\t` is tab-delimited...

Comment: But the excel file isn't comma separated? Thanks.

Comment: To read an excel sheet from the console I recommend this article from R: http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-data.html#Reading-Excel-spreadsheets

Comment: You said you saved as CSV... "Comma Separated Values." If it's actually tab-delimited, then `\t` is fine...

Comment: The guy in the video is DEFINITELY using R-Studio, by the way. I just watched it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using the R basic program (not basic in core functionality, just basic in terms of user interface features) that you probably downloaded from http://www.r-project.org/

The video you are watching is running a productive user interface called RStudio. You can download it for free from here: http://www.rstudio.com/ Works the same for all your purposes.